# Rails redirect_to "www.somewebsite.com" with GET/POST parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to issue a redirect_to in one of my controllers to a fully qualified URL + I want to pass in some parameters

In the controller for site A I do:

```
redirect_to: "www.siteB.com/my_controller/my_action?my_parameter=123"
```

Is there a nicer way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 6):

If SiteB is running the same app (i.e. the routes are the same for that server), then you can build the redirect you describe with:

```
redirect_to :host => "www.siteB.com", 
            :controller => "my_controller", 
            :action => "my_action",  
            :my_parameter => 123
```

Notice that any keys not handled by `url_for` are automatically encoded as parameters.

Comment: This solution assumes that SiteA's routes.rb has a route that matches that controller/action pair. This isn't a problem if you've kept the default routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently pass a host:

```
redirect_to { :host => "www.siteB.com", :controller => "my_controller", :action => "my_action",  :id => 123 }
```

Check out the documentation for [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000649).

Comment: This solution assumes that SiteA's routes.rb has a route that matches that controller/action pair. This isn't a problem if you've kept the default routes.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of the other responses. If you set up a controller defining the path in your routes.rb of site A, you can use the generated url helpers. Just override the :host as an argument.

Example:

Site A Routes.rb:

```
...
map.resource whatever
...
```

Site A Controller:

```
...
redirect_to edit_whatever_url(:host => "www.siteB.com", :my_parameter => 123)
...
```

So long as SiteB's web server (rails or otherwise) recognizes the `http://www.siteB.com/whaterver/edit?my_parameter=123` you're good.

**Caveat:** Keep in mind that redirecting a Post with 302 has specific consequences as defined in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). In a nutshell it means that a user will be asked to reconfirm their post to the new URL, before the redirected post can succeed.